# Differentiability of a function with euclidean norm

Tags: real-analysis, differential

If $\| \, \, \|$ denotes the euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, is $f: x \mapsto \dfrac{x}{\| x \|^2}$ differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{ 0 \}$ ?

I tried to use the fact that $\| \, \, \|$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{ 0 \}$, or to compute $f(x + h) - f(x)$, but couldn't get anything from there.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac1{g(x)}x$ where $g$ is differentiable and (on $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0 \}$) does not take the value $0.$

Comment: Look at [Quotient of multivariable differentiable functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660976/quotient-of-multivariable-differentiable-functions)

Comment: Thank you for your answer !